# R: Create environment in .Rprofile

Tags: r, rprofile

When I use following snippet in my .Rprofile file of a project:

```
.env <- new.env()

.env$test <- function() {
  print("sfsdfsd")
}
```

and open the project in RStudio, ".env" isn't created:

`ls(envir=.env)` 
returns 
`Error in ls(envir = .env) : object '.env' not found`

`.env$test()`
returns
`Error: object '.env' not found`

Running the same code in RStudio is working though:

`ls(envir=.env)` 
then returns `[1] "test"`

Creating an environment via .RProfile file is recommended a lot (eg [this blog post](http://gettinggeneticsdone.blogspot.com.es/2013/07/customize-rprofile.html)).

Has RStudio changed its behaviour?

Comment: If I make this Rprofile and start Rstudio in that directory, .env is defined. Are you sure R is starting in the correct directory?

Comment: Add `cat("Hello, world\n")` to your .Rprofile and then start a fresh R session to be sure that your .Rprofile is being run.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes everything else in my Rprofile.site is working, also an additional ```cat("Hello, world\````

Comment: It's working for me inside a project's .Rprofile file. That's enough for me at the moment.